# Quickly see all message from a sender in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I'm trying to move over to Gmail.

Here's something I do all the time in another mailer. I receive a message from somebody ("LYN LINDY", for example). While reading this message I want to see all of the other messages in my archive from the same person. Is there an easy way to do that in Gmail?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the advanced search operator. In the search box, type `from: lyn` and you'll get an auto-complete of email addresses.  Pick the one you want and you'll get all email from that person.  You can also use `to: lyn` to see email you sent them.

Comment: You could also use the labs Quick Links feature (http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=145401) to make this operation easier.

Answer (score 6):

On June 26, 2018 I solved it like this: checkmark one of the messages from the sender.  Now click on the three dots at the top ribbon and select "filter messages like this" and all the emails from that sender will appear, just like it used to with the "recent mail from" feature

Comment: I've sent feedback to Gmail about this.  It's now 4 clicks versus a hover and 1 click, and I use this all day long.  It's not a trivial change.

Comment: it is also only half a solution. You want to search for `FROM:sender@example.com AND TO:sender@example.com` as the old hover solution did. the "filter messages like this" only includes the `FROM:` part, and it also only works on the sender, not copied recipients.

Comment: When looking at a list of email messages, Right Click on the senders name, then choose  "Find emails from senders-name"

Comment: Thanks for these details, this has been so frustrating for me.

Answer (score 3):

In the newest version of Gmail, the person's name appears on the right side of the page with a few icons underneath it.  One icon is a small downward arrow - if you hover over it, it says "More actions."  Click on it, and choose "Recent mail from."  Very handy feature.

Comment: Thanks. It is handy, but it doesn't show everything, alas.

Answer (score 2):

While either looking at the list of email messages or an individual message, hover your mouse pointer over the sender's name. You'll get a popup card with information on the sender (more if they're in your contacts). Down at the bottom is a link labeled "Emails".

If you click that link it will run a custom search to show you all of the messages where that email address is in either the To: field or the From: field. To wit, it automatically generates a search string for you like this:

```
from:sender@example.com OR to:sender@example.com
```

---

Unfortunately in the "new" Gmail preview (early 2018), this functionality has been removed, forcing you to put in the search by hand. I hope that they restore it, as I used it quite frequently. Until then, the search string above still obviously works.